# Unable to install/update any nuget packages using VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

I’ve run into a problem whereby I cannot install any NugetPackages. This includes updating existing packages, whereby it will remove the old package and fail to install the updated one, leaving my solutions in a broken state!

Here’s an example of the output from the Package Manager console when trying to install SpecFlow for example:

```
PM> Install-Package SpecRun.SpecFlow -verbose
  GET http://path:to/nugetserver/api/nuget/nuget-repos/FindPackagesById()?id='SpecRun.SpecFlow'
  OK http://path:to/nugetserver/api/nuget/nuget-repos/FindPackagesById()?id='SpecRun.SpecFlow' 780ms
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.5.2' with respect to project 'Framework\MyService.Data', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.5.2' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.5.2'
Resolved actions to install package 'SpecRun.SpecFlow.1.5.2'
For adding package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' to project 'MyService.Data' that targets 'net451'.
For adding package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' to project 'MyService.Data' that targets 'net451'.
Adding package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' to folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages'
Added package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' to folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' does not exist in project 'MyService.Data'
Removing package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' from folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages'
Removed file 'SpecFlow.2.1.0.nupkg' from folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0'.
Removed folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages\SpecFlow.2.1.0'.
Removed package 'SpecFlow.2.1.0' from folder 'F:\tfs\MyService\Main\packages'
Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'TechTalk.SpecFlow'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package SpecRun.SpecFlow -verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

As you can see, it downloads the packages (and I can see it appear on the file system in the packages folder) but it then fails to install and deletes it from disk. I’ve searched about and verified that the packages folder *isn’t* checked in to source control by accident. This is happening on any solution I open using Visual Studio 2015.I’ve tried the console and the Package manager GUI and both fail.

Things seem to be working in VS2013 (which is one of the workarounds I’ve been using but not a long term solution).

VS 2015 is fully up to date as is Nuget.

Thanks

Comment: Do you test it in other VS2015 machine? What is your VS2015's version information? How about uninstalling the package firstly? And then install the new one singly. I use the VS2015 Enterprise version 14.0.2524.00 with update 3, it works well in my side if I install the latest package directly.

Comment: Did you try restarting the VS?

Comment: I have similar problem and it exists cause of SpecFlow. Not 100% sure cause I haven't solved it yet